# Binary Searching random returns

Tags: binary-search

I have problem with Binary Searching. I want to my function returns the smallest(first which function meets) index of searching value. My function sometimes returns random value of index. For example if I choose 999999 and in array there are 2 index of this value there is returned random value from this two. How to fix it?

Comment: I suggest going through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Can you please provide an isolated case with minimum code and example input and output.

Comment: For example: input 999998, output: 999995 but if i print array i can see that searchedValue 999998 is on index 999994 and 999995. I want to my function return the smallest index where my searchedValue appear ( in this example 999994) but it returns random. What should i change?

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to continue the binary search until `vector[index] == searchValue && (index == 0 || vector[index - 1] != searchValue)`